# How to get form data with multi select in checkboxs - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a form that I want to get all his values, and convert them to json object.

the problem is that I not get the multiselect fields, just one field.
this is my code
what I am missing?

```
let reportDropDowns = $('#getReport').serialize();
        reportDropDowns = decodeURI(reportDropDowns);
        let reportDropDownsJson = {};

   
    reportDropDownsJson =  JSON.parse('{"' + reportDropDowns.replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}', function(key, value) { return key===""?value:decodeURIComponent(value) });
```

this is my html
[image]

Comment: Kindly add the actual HTML of the form to the question.

Comment: ^ agreed with the above, the serialize method will only return **successful controls** which are defined in the official documentation, meaning if your HTML is not proper peer W3C you might see problems with what you are looking to achieve. See: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: how I can copy the html from the dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of serializing the data directly via `.serialize()`, you should instead use [`.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to get the data as an array. You can then manipulate the array into an object/JSON. Try this

```
let reportDropDownsJson = {};
$('#getReport').serializeArray().forEach(({name, value}) => {
    if( reportDropDownsJson.hasOwnProperty(name) ){
        if( !Array.isArray(reportDropDownsJson[name]) ){
            reportDropDownsJson[name] = [reportDropDownsJson[name]];
        }
        
        reportDropDownsJson[name].push(value);
    }else{
        reportDropDownsJson[name] = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey it worked however I can not manipulate it to json

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify(reportDropDownsJson)` to convert it to JSON string.